# put SELECT COUNT(*) statement result into int variable

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I have a `SELECT COUNT(*)` statement in `C#/ASP.NET` and I want to store the result as an `int` to use as an `IF` condition. However I am getting an error in visual studio:

> Error:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.

It tells me its occurring at the **int temp** line. The columns I'm accessing in the database table are of text type.

```
conn.Open();    
String checkEmail = "select count(*) from Players where PlayerEmail= '" + txtEmailLogIn.Text + "'";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkEmail, conn);
int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
conn.Close();
if (temp > 0) 
{

}
```

Comment: This needs to be parametrized.  Using EXISTS rather than COUNT is more optimal if you don't need to actually know the count.

Comment: Don't build SQL queries from un-sanitized user input, your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/07/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-sql.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your SQL. You can't use `=` when comparing `TEXT` data types, instead you can use `LIKE`:

```
String checkEmail = "select count(*) from Players where PlayerEmail LIKE '" + txtEmailLogIn.Text + "'";
```

Be warned though, that you are opening yourself up to SQL injection attacks when composing SQL strings like this.

Comment: @user3087192 Great, though I'd love to know why I got a downvote for it! :)

Answer (score 0):

DavidG's answer above works. However, if you have the opportunity to change the database schema, you could also fix the error by changing the PlayerEmail column from text to varchar(max). The text data type has been [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993(v=sql.90).aspx) since at least 2005.